# If the pair matches, fill with a specific color, if not, fill with different color - but only aplicable to cell that are not BLANK

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I compared two pairs of columns (column A and B with column C and D) to see if they matches.
If they do, column A and B are filled with green, if they don't, they are filled with orange.
The problem is that when I have a blank space in a B cell, it's also filled with orange and I want to avoid this.

This are the two conditional formatting formulas:

=AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A1&$B1,INDEX($E$1:$E$30&$F$1:$F$30,,),0))) - (green as fill color)
=NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A1&$B1,INDEX($E$1:$E$30&$F$1:$F$30,,),0))) - (orange as fill color)

As example - this is how it looks right now (those are columns A and B, I didn't capture C and D columns because they are not relevant in this example ):

[image: How it looks right now]

This is how I want them to look:

[image: How I want it to look]

I can't find a solution to ignore the blank space from the second formula so it will only apply orange when is not a match but when the cells are not blank.

I don't know how to make

=NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A1&$B1,INDEX($E$1:$E$30&$F$1:$F$30,,),0)))

to ignore blank spaces so I'm asking for you help!

Thank you!

--

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wrap in an if like if(A1="","",then your stuff)

Comment: Are you expecting Excel to understand Portuguese? :-)

Comment: @SolarMike Thank you for your quick answer. Adding that If command fills the entire column A and cell that is not matching from column B. Adding if command with B1 instead of A1, fills only the cell that does not match from column A. I edit the post with examples.

Comment: @Dominique Thanks for your answer, but no, I'm not expecting that nor I've asked that.